# python-eve: 405 error on PATCH item / document

Tags: python, mongodb, request, http-status-code-405, eve

I am using an [eve-API](http://python-eve.org/) to access a MongoDB. However, if I want to `PATCH` an item (document) I get a 405 error.

I can access the document I want to update using curl as follows:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000/simulations/20151223_011329620
```

The API returns the desired document:

```
{
    "_updated": "Wed, 23 Dec 2015 00:13:29 GMT",
    "regenerator": "565e12c58b724d7884cd02bb",
    "identifier": "20151223_011329620",
    "_etag": "9c50633f1bf34bcefb84237ce2477066529f3c0e",
    "_links": {
        "parent": {
            "title": "home",
            "href": "/"
        },
        "self": {
            "title": "Simulation",
            "href": "simulations/5679e72904c8880421b0abfa"
        },
        "collection": {
            "title": "simulations",
            "href": "simulations"
        }
    },
    "_created": "Wed, 23 Dec 2015 00:13:29 GMT",
    "status": "pending",
    "_id": "5679e72904c8880421b0abfa",
    "sectors": ["565e12c58b724d7884cd02b9", "565e12c58b724d7884cd02ba"]
}
```

I tried using curl in order to update the document via a `PATCH` request like this:

```
curl -X PATCH -d '{"status": "pending"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/simulations/20151223_011329620
```

Since this gave me an 405 error I read the [docs](http://python-eve.org/features.html#data-integrity-and-concurrency-control) telling that I should provide a valid `etag`. Due to this I tried:

```
curl -H "If-Match: 9c50633f1bf34bcefb84237ce2477066529f3c0e" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH http://127.0.0.1:5000/simulations/20151223_011329620 -d '{"status": "pending"}'
```

Which gives me the same 405 error:

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"code": 405, "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}}
```

I don't know why I am not allowed to `PATCH` the desired item (document) since the global config is as follows:

```
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
```

According to the [docs](http://python-eve.org/config.html#resource-item-endpoints) I can overwrite these global settings with the lowercase equivalent (`resource_methods` and
`item_methods`) in the endpoint's definition. Hence neither those seem to have default values nor did I specify those in the endpoint's definition (`config` snippet below) I cannot find the reason for this error.

```
config = {
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': r'regex("\d{8}_\d{9}(_\d{3})?")',
        'field': 'identifier'
    },
    'schema': schema,
}
```

Comment: Hi Albert, are you able to make this work ?

Comment: I am just using the `_id` as described in the answer below and provide the `_etag` as stated in the docs . I did not do any further investigations on the `id_field` related approach since I have both my own `identifier` and the `_id` in my data array. So at the end this was rather a question for the sake of conformity to the other parts of my API-interaction...

Comment: Okk, thanks ...So, i am not sure id_field: 'identifier' is working or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default only _id field can be used for PATCH. If you want to PATCH using some other field then you need to declare an `ID_FIELD` named field in that config which will point to some other field in the config, like "identifier" in your case.

EDIT:

> `ID_FIELD` : Name of the field used to uniquely identify resource items within the database. You want this field to be properly indexed on the database. Can be overridden by resource settings. Defaults to _id.

For more, read here how to set ID_FIELD in settings.py file: http://python-eve.org/config.html

Comment: How can I declare the needed `id_field` since I am using this as an additional lookup but not as an UUID?

Comment: if we defined another field called "id_field", how the url will be for patch ?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit please.

Comment: @sapam: Where are you stuck?

Comment: i was trying the same but getting 405 Method not allowed error. So, in your case do you add  config = { ... "id_field" : "identifier" }  ?

Comment: Or please update your new config in your post as update, so somone who read this post could get the idea better. thanks in adv.

Comment: oh you explain in the above post.

Comment: hi @James did you find out the solution for this? i've been stuck in a similar situation btw